# How to check if the NSMutableArray already has (__bridge id) object in the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, compare, abrecordref

I am trying to add ABRecordRef item into my NSMutableArray. Just learned that It's needed to cast the C TypeDef into Objective-C id type using (_bridge id). So, before adding new items into the array, I want to check if the object is already in the array. Therefore, i tried using [nsmutablearray containsObject] but it does not seem to be working. Duplicate items still get added into the array. Do you know what could be wrong here?

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
    if (![_buddiesList containsObject:(__bridge id)person]) {
        [_buddiesList addObject:(__bridge id)person];
        NSLog(@"Added");
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: have you bridged all persons and then added?

Comment: Nope, here I just want to add a person only if the user taps on the tableview cell. Does bridge all person mean converting the entire contact list into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no NS-equivalent to `ABRecordRef` and `-containsObject:` simply calls `-isEqual:` on all its objects to determine if there is a duplicate already included or not, so your approach can't work.

I suggest writing a wrapper class around `ABRecordRef` and implementing your own `-isEqual:` method there.

**Update:**
As pointed out by @omz, it *does* work, because `CFEqual()` is called, thanks! Using a wrapper class around ABRecordRef is still a good idea, though.

Comment: Actually, you can send `isEqual:` to a `CFTypeRef` (like `ABRecordRef`), it'll basically call `CFEqual()`. The OP's code should work (and when I just tested this, it did, so I suspect something else  is wrong).

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `containsObject:` call is failing to report the duplicate is that `NSArray` uses the `NSObject` method `-isEqual:` to determine equality, and CF types such as `ABRecordRef` do not have this method. We need to find a better way to determine equality.

The most efficient way to do this is to use an Objective-C wrapper around the AddressBook APIs, transforming each record into a *bona fide* `NSObject` instead of just bridge-casting it. [Jim Dovey's iPhoneContacts project](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/iPhoneContacts) is a well-written solution for this. To build an equality testing method on top of this, just add an `isEqual:` method that uses the technique shown below for comparing the record IDs.

Alternatively, you can keep things as they are, but do a linear scan over the array each time you're about to add a record. Something like this:

```
BOOL foundMatch = NO;
for(id buddy in self.buddiesList)
{
    if(ABRecordGetRecordID(buddy) == ABRecordGetRecordID(person))
    {
        foundMatch = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing the record ID rather than the name might be more elegant.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use comparison by record ID rather than name. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try cheking your array objects against isKindOfClass.

For instance:

if ([[*buddiesList objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass: (*_bridge id)person]) {

Do some stuff;

}